# SP2010 List Access DB

Tags: 2010, microsoft-access

I have an problem with a SharePoint list and an Access DB. They are one in the same however the problem I am having is that the field types do not seem to add up.

In Access when I go to design mode I get the following message: 
"Table 'Master List' is a linked table whose design can't be modified. If you want to add or remove fields or change their properties or data types, you must do so in the source database" - I expect this because it wants me to configure it in SharePoint 2010.

I have this field "copy of invoice" which in access is a combo box, value list and has four options. However, on the SharePoint 2010 it shows as a signal line of text and doesn't have any data validation that fits to make it fit the four options in the Access Database.

Ultimately, is there a way to resync it all up so the acecs DB matches the SharePoint list (I've tried refreshing it)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I needed to right click the link table in the left hand navigation on Access >more options>refresh list to update the field settings in Access